# Help with installing Ubuntu 16.04.5 (black screen)

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, hard-drive, windows, mbr

I have HDD and flash drive and i want install ubuntu from flash
When im boot from flash,only black screen (iso from getmyos and ubuntu)
Flash:FAT32
CPU:amd64
On VirtualBox it work
On wibu 20.04 on other HDD work too
Now on this HDD Windows Vista and i want install ubuntu or kali
Help please

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Kali forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Kali so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Possibly useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck